# How to design API around dynamic endpoints?

Tags: node.js

I am designing an API wrapper based off of an existing wrapper for to interface with a third-party service.

There are two methods for public and private requests, and to determine which to use the API method checks to see if the endpoint is in either the public or private array of the methods object:

```
function api(method, params, callback) {
    var methods = {
        public: ['countrycodes', 'payment_methods/CA'],
        private: ['ad-get', 'ad-get/ad_id', 'myself', 
        'dashboard', 'dashboard/released', 'dashboard/canceled', 'dashboard/closed', 
        'dashboard/released/buyer', 'dashboard/canceled/buyer', 'dashboard/closed/buyer',
        'dashboard/released/seller', 'dashboard/canceled/seller', 'dashboard/closed/seller',
        'wallet-send'
        ]
    };
    if(methods.public.indexOf(method) !== -1) {
        return publicMethod(method, params, callback);
    }
    else if(methods.private.indexOf(method) !== -1) {
        return privateMethod(method, params, callback);
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that there are parameters that need to be added to the URL, for example you can see : 'payment_methods/CA'. If I added all the countries there would be 50.

Also, you can see with the 'dashboard/canceled/buyer' methods, this is not a very elegant design.

I have a couple ideas, but they are not very straightforward. What's a logical and elegant way to allow parameters to be added to the path but still check that the method is valid?

Comment: You can add another condition to your if statement:
if(methods.public.indexOf(method) !== -1 || method.startsWith('payment_methods'))

Comment: have you considered using express.js with node to handle your requests. express js can be quite handy to deal with dynamic parameters.

Comment: @Anthony, if 'payment_methods' is not at the beginning, then you can have your if statement as  if(methods.public.indexOf(method) !== -1 || method.match(/payment_methods/))... however, hars's suggestion is worth looking into.  It can handle regex well too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. Based on that I found that lodash has a nice startsWith method which I'll use since the beginning path is in the same place everytime. Thanks guys.